# Elasticsearch dropping data

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an issue in which I'm trying to figure out, over the last 48h (at time of writing) I've had elastic search suddenly drop 2 indices for no apparent reason. The only thing I've been able to connect them together are these lines in the error log:

```
[2018-09-13 17:10:44,160][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Madeline Joyce] [readme] creating index, cause [api], templates [], shards [5]/[1], mappings []
[2018-09-13 17:10:44,320][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Madeline Joyce][readme] create_mapping [howtogetmydataback]
[2018-09-13 17:10:44,330][INFO ][cluster.routing.allocation] [Madeline Joyce] Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [YELLOW] (reason: [shards started [[rea$
[2018-09-13 17:10:49,512][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Madeline Joyce] [.kibana] creating index, cause [api], templates [], shards [1]/[1], mappings [confi$
[2018-09-13 17:10:49,531][INFO ][cluster.routing.allocation] [Madeline Joyce] Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [YELLOW] (reason: [shards started [[.ki$
[2018-09-13 17:13:26,306][ERROR][license.plugin.core      ] [Madeline Joyce]
```

Both error messages are similar in output, I'm running Elastic Search 2.4.6 on Ubuntu 14.04. Any help would be grateful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see any ERROR message in your log.

Comment: I know its not a true error message, but I can't ignore this particular output as these lines appear in the error log and they occur at the point when the indices disappear from Kibana and Elasticsearch.

Comment: You should provide the full log output, because it seems end of lines are being cut off

Comment: unfortunately that's how ES is outputting it, plus half the log is useless as its saying a licence has expired

Comment: I'm not sure ES cuts off the end of lines by itself. It must be something else